# Matlab : color code portion of the line

Tags: matlab

I have the following array that contains **ALL** of my points:

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];

y = [1,9,8,5,2,8,1,4,3,11,13,15,16,13,12];

I plot my blue line with the following command:

```
plot(x,y, 'blue');
```

I want to color code sections of the generated plot.

Example:

x1 = [2,3,4,11,12,13];

numbers in x range of x1 should be red on the x axis on the original plot.

Looking at [this post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/3368-how-to-change-the-color-of-a-graph-only-in-a-particular-section) , it is recommended by the author to draw out different lines, based on some qualifying boolean.

Hence, I have updated my code to be as follows:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
y = [1,9,8,5,2,8,1,4,3,11,13,15,16,13,12];
x1 = [2,3,4,11,12,13];

canPlot = ismember(x, x1);
hold on;
plot(x,y, 'blue');
plot(x(canPlot), y(canPlot), 'red');
hold off;
```

However, the generated graph connects "disconnected" points. Here is a photo of the problem:

[image]

As you can see above, the two segments x1 when it equates to 4 and x1 when it equates to 11 are connected. I don't want them to be connected. How can I get rid of that connecting line **without** splitting x1 into to sequential variables?

I.e

These points should be connected to formulate a red line:

2,3,4

11,12,13

These points should **not** be connected to formulate a red line:

4,11

Comment: You say _numbers in x range of x1 should be red_, but `plot` colors _lines_ rather than points. So what's the criterion for lines?

Comment: you are right. poor wording on my end. I want to connect "points" into a line only if they are sequential. I do not want to connect points into a line if they are not sequnetially connected. i.e x1=2,3,4 should connect as red, x1=11,12,13 should connect, but x1=4,11 should not

Comment: And when are values in `x1` considered to be sequential? Should they be consecutive integers, or should they appear consecutively in `x`?

Comment: values in x will alwats be sequential. ( increments of 1 ) values in x1 should be considered sequential if they are increments of 1

Comment: @Wolfie not a duplicate. also, unsure of the reason for downvote.

Comment: Not my downvote. Why isn't it a duplicate? The criteria for colouring the line is different, but the solution to that question shows how to create different coloured line depending on a condition, where the sections are not connected. That appears to be exactly what you're asking for?

Comment: @Wolfie i've went through the reccoemdantions from that post before. i'll give it one more go. investigating

Comment: @Wolfie i guess tired / angry eyes don't do it correct the first time. ;) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NaN` as a delimiter between the sequential values in your vector to plot, and then `plot` divide it into seperated lines.

I don't know about a comfort way in Matlab to append and add values in the middle of a vector, so I'll create a new vector of NaN's and then will copy the desired values to the matching indices:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
y = [1,9,8,5,2,8,1,4,3,11,13,15,16,13,12];
x1 = [2,3,4,11,12,13];

xPlot=nan(1,length(x1)+sum(diff(x1)>1));
xPlot((1:length(x1))+[0 cumsum(diff(x1)>1)])=x(ismember(x,x1));
yPlot=nan(1,length(x1)+sum(diff(x1)>1));
yPlot((1:length(x1))+[0 cumsum(diff(x1)>1)])=y(ismember(x,x1));
figure; plot(x,y,'b')
hold on; plot(xPlot,yPlot,'r')
```

[image]